# How to convert a string to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, encoding, integer, decimal

so I have this Python code here:

```
for binary_value in binary_values:
    an_integer = int(binary_value, 2)
    ascii_character = chr(an_integer)
    ascii_string += ascii_character
        if len(ascii_string) == 151:
            print(ascii_string)
```

It converts my binary code to text, the text it should convert the binary into is a string of numbers, it is text encoded in decimal. Here is the decimal (not actual decimal I'm using just for showcase purposes):

```
72 101 121 32 116 104 101 114 101 33
```

The issue is that it's a string, and I need it to be a list of integers and look something like this:

```
decimal=[72,101,121,32,116,104,101,114,101,33]
```

How would I achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: assuming you have `72 101 121 32 116 104 101 114 101 33` as string from your problem statement and you need to convert it to list of int `decimal=[72,101,121,32,116,104,101,114,101,33]`. tmp = <Your String of numbers>  you can try this `decimal = list(map(int, tmp.split()))`

Comment: Please update your code with an example of `binary_values`. Plus, what is `ascii_string`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
s = '72 101 121 32 116 104 101 114 101 33'
a = list(map(int, s.split()))
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[72, 101, 121, 32, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet could help:

```
binary_values = [ '0b1001000', '0b1100101', '0b1111001', '0b100000', '0b1110100', '0b1101000', '0b1100101', '0b1110010', '0b1100101', '0b100001' ]
decimals = [ int(binary_value, 2) for binary_value in binary_values ]
print( decimals )
```

> ```
> [72, 101, 121, 32, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 33]
> ```

Check up:

```
print( ''.join( [ chr(x) for x in decimals ] ) )
```

> ```
> 'Hey there!'
> ```